# Laravel : UPDATE if exist else INSERT?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

Is there a method in Laravel (Eloquent, Fluent...) which UPDATEs a row and if this row doesn't exist it will be INSERTed?

Answer (score 2):

Dunno id Laravel has such a method, but with mysql you can do that with a query like this

```
INSERT INTO t SET c1='foo', c2='bar' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c2='bar'
```

You have to have an unique index on this table to make trick work

Comment: To be more specific, the `UNIQUE` index would have to cover `c1` in this particular case, as it's that index that's used to detect a duplicate.

Comment: An example to demonstrate http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/daf5f/1, and the mysql documentation http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html